# Qué entienden en esta canción por ‘se le enlutó’?

Tags: significado-en-contexto

> Grillos y sapos, lechuzas tuertas
> fueron la orquesta que dirigí.
> Cayeron lluvias de agua y de balas
> salvé la vida porque hubo un dios.
> Silbé las letras y a mi guitarra
> el encordado **se le enlutó**.
> [Postales del Alma (Chacarera)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zen2fk_w_-8)

Buenas, gente. Así dice la segunda estrofa de esta oscura canción. Traigo esta especie de pregunta porque no termino de decidir acerca de cuál es el significado de *enlutar* que se hace presente en este caso, obviamente esto asumiendo que hay un único significado posible o que al menos debería destacarse claramente del resto.

Según el DLE—mejor que lo que aparece ahí no encontré nada—hay tres significados posibles del término (no lo conocía):

- cubrir de luto (vestirse, supongo)
- oscurecer
- entristecer

Lo que me gustaría, no lo digo por caretear, es que al menos lean o escuchen la canción y piensen sobre lo que entienden acerca de lo que está relatando el tipo—al menos que ya la conozcan de prepo, algo que considero poco probable pero en ese caso omítase esta introducción. A continuación, les digo qué es lo que entiendo en general de la canción y en particular sobre esa línea (*spoiler alert*).

La canción de alguna forma hace una especie de resumen combinando la vida del autor y de la historia en general del siglo anterior, pero en particular se centra en la evolución de la música con un tinte medio pesimista. En este sentido, la acepción a la que deberíamos atenernos claramente es la tercera: como el tipo empezó a silbar las melodías de las canciones, en lugar de tocarlas en la guitarra, ésta ‘se puso triste’. Básicamente, es una especie de metáfora a cómo decayó el folclore en favor del pop. Pero bueno, a lo mejor la pregunta es demasiado ‘folclórica’ para que pueda ser respondida en este sitio.

Ahora, me gustaría escuchar sus opiniones. Si alguien tiene algo interesante que pueda aportar, lo voy a leer sin ningún problema. Un saludo.

Comment: No veo clara la relación de causalidad entre silbar las letras y que la guitarra se enlute; es decir que la primera provoque la segunda. Coincido contigo en que lo más probable es que ese enlutado signifique que su música se hizo más triste. ¿Pero el pop es más triste que el folk? Quizás ese entristecer es solo fruto del paso de la adolescencia a la madurez.

Comment: Todo depende de como se interpreta el encordado. Para mi, eso quiere decir que la guitarra con sus cuerdas, se pusó triste al oír la melodía o letras silbadas. –La imagen podría tambien ser la de una mujer (la guitarra es muchas veces ententido como una mujer en poesia, etc.) ...Uno se puede entristecer con cualquier cosa. Es muy individual.

Comment: Estar de luto es un estado ante la muerte de un ser querido, que se solía representar externamente vistiendo de negro (en la cultura mediterránea y por extensión en Latinoamérica). En este caso hace referencia a la extrema tristeza que pone de luto a la guitarra.

Comment: @JLPrieto No entendí, quién se puso triste, él o la guitarra?

Comment: @tac "Silbé las letras y a mi guitarra / el encordado se le enlutó." Entiendo que él se puso triste y la guitarra, por solidaridad se vistió de negro

Comment: La pregunta espera una interpretacion de la figura "enlutar". Diría que naturalmente se interpreta "que la guitarra adopta un tono triste" Eso en cuanto a que 'enlutar' refleja un dolor por una pérdida. Por otro lado, he de decir que los versos no me guían a comprensiones como las que se sugieren. Por empezar no parece siquiera claro que la aludida tristeza sea causada por el silbo  (más bien parecería "que acompaña" el ánimo de quien la ejecuta) La licencia poética de transferir sentimientos al instrumento habilita una latitud de acepciones, y esa es la que me provoca.

Comment: Menos aún, —ni asistido por la explicaciión del supuesto trasfóndo alegórico que vendría simbolizado en tal trama— puedo, para nada, adivinar o percibir el caso como el de un enfrentamiento de géneros musicales.  Francamente se me escapa ver eso explicado de la búsqueda artística. En mi caso no alcanzo a leer una metáfora sobre géneros musicales en disputa, ni el supuesto dolimiento  de la guitarra (pretendidamente, la representación del Folcklore) enlutada por el silbo, (que leo vendría a ser el Pop)

Comment: Es interesante la discusión, pero quizás la subjetividad de la temática hace que no cuadre mucho para el tipo de preguntas que el sitio admita, o con las que pueda beneficiarse

Comment: @ipp Pero entonces cómo cuadraría eso con el resto de la canción? O por el contrario, dirías que simplemente la letra es casual y que no hay un significado o un mensaje específico que el autor quiera transmitir?

Comment: @tac. No lo se. Claro que puede ser que el autor  buscara decir eso. Yo sólo opiné que esa comprensión no se me hace evidente en la letra de la canción